# STRING_8 does not conform to STRING_UC in is_equal

Tags: type-mismatch, eiffel

I'm trying to build [xplain2sql](https://github.com/berenddeboer/xplain2sql) using [Gobo compiler and its tools](https://github.com/gobo-eiffel/gobo). After issuing `geant compile` command I get a lot of similar errors:

> [CATCALL] class SQL_GENERATOR_TSQL65 (SQL_GENERATOR,2610,5): type
>   'STRING_8' of actual argument #1 does not conform to type 'UC_STRING'
>   of formal argument in feature `is_equal' in class 'UC_STRING'

Above error refers to [the last line](https://github.com/berenddeboer/xplain2sql/blob/704153164e4b1bb54273ff78690d2e8f0ccad3cd/src/sql_generator.e#L2610) of this code:

```
    sql_infix_expression (a_left: XPLAIN_EXPRESSION; an_operator: STRING; a_right: XPLAIN_EXPRESSION): STRING
        -- SQL expression for multiplication/division, etc.
    require
        valid_left: a_left /= Void
        valid_right: a_right /= Void
        operator_not_empty: an_operator /= Void and then not an_operator.is_empty
    local
        left_value,
        right_value: STRING
    do
        if
            an_operator.is_equal (once "+") and then
```

I don't know Eiffel, I just want to compile this code. There were other build errors which I was able to fix using some common sense and experience from other programming languages but I don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you could use `same_string (..)` as replacement for `is_equal (..)` .

Comment: This worked for some errors but not all . Some of them point to the body of `equal (..)` (in standard library) which invokes `is_equal (..)`. Is there a strings-only replacement for `equal (..)` just like there was for `is_equal (..)`? I'm trying to find it in documentation but without any luck.

Comment: I've had some success with changing some `equal (..)` calls to `is_equal(..)`  to check if error messages are generated by these particular lines or code and then modifying them to use `same_string (..)`. This is tedious work but it seems to work.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to further help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045431/getting-stack-trace-from-geant

Comment: The issue is related to a redefinition of `is_equal` in `UC_STRING` that takes an argument of type `like Current`, i.e. `UC_STRING`. Changing `is_equal` to `same_string` works in this particular case because `same_string` takes `STRING_8` as an argument. This does not solve the general issue reported for the class `ANY` because `same_string` cannot be used there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in the Gobo compiler that turns CAT-call errors into warnings, but it did not help me to complete the build successfully. However, the project compiles fine with [EiffelStudio](https://www.eiffel.org/downloads):

```
ec -config xplain2sql.ecf -c_compile -finalize
```

The resulting executable can be found in `EIFGENs\xplain2sql\F_code`.