# Getting stack trace from geant

Tags: stack-trace, type-mismatch, eiffel

I'm trying to compile a project (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043406/string-8-does-not-conform-to-string-uc-in-is-equal/)) using Gobo compiler and its tools and I'm getting error messages refering to standard library `equal(..)`. I'm sure that error is somewhere in the code I have and not in standard library but I don't know how to get some more info from `geant`. I'd like to know which class, function, line of code from my code invoked `equal(..)` or any other standard library function which might call it. And yes, I've already tried going through all `equal(..)`s in my code.

Error messages I get are like this:

> [CATCALL] class SQL_GENERATOR_TSQL65 (ANY,95,8): type 'STRING_8' of actual argument #1 does not conform to type 'UC_STRING' of formal argument in feature `is_equal' in class 'UC_STRING'

This points to `library\free_elks\src\elks\kernel\any.e`:

```
    frozen equal (a: detachable ANY; b: like a): BOOLEAN
        -- Are `a' and `b' either both void or attached
        -- to objects considered equal?
    do
        if a = Void then
            Result := b = Void
        else
            Result := b /= Void and then
                        a.is_equal (b) -- <<<<<<< THIS LINE
        end
    ensure
        definition: Result = (a = Void and b = Void) or else
                    ((a /= Void and b /= Void) and then
                    a.is_equal (b))
    end
```

Comment: Can you show your code, that caused the errors. If the compiler is not helping you find it, then use your revision control system to help you: Ask it what changes you made since the code last compiled? If you make lots of small changes (test driven), then you should find the change and thus the error very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Reported CAT-calls are system errors (as opposed to class errors), i.e. appear as a result of the whole system analysis. The class `UC_STRING` redefines the feature `is_equal`. As a result it can be used only with arguments of type `UC_STRING` (or its descendants).

Some code treats `UC_STRING` as `STRING_8` (`UC_STRING` inherits from `STRING_8`). As soon as `UC_STRING` is attached to an entity of type `STRING_8`, the code is at risk of getting the CAT-call. Here is an example:

```
s: STRING_8
t: STRING_8
u: UC_STRING
...
s := u
if equal (s, t) then ...
```

The code of `equal` that you mention calls `is_equal` on an instance of `UC_STRING`, but receives `STRING_8` as an argument. However, the version of `is_equal` in `UC_STRING` can handle only `UC_STRING` as an argument, not `STRING_8`. That's why you get the error.

The issue can be solved by

- changing the argument type of `is_equal` in `UC_STRING` to accept `STRING_8`
- removing all reattachments of `UC_STRING` to `STRING_8`
- disabling the CAT-call errors

The last one seems to be the best in your case.